# Principal server status when it comes back after failure (Mirroring)

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have 2 servers set in Mirroring without Witness - Transaction Safety OFF for some databases and Safety Full on most critical. I know what are the failover scenarios when Principal or Mirror server fails and what needs to be done to bring the db's online but I never tested one specific scenario:

- The Principal server has a crash, say unexpected shutdown, or reboot.
- No DBA is on duty to manage the failover
- The Mirror server will take this as it was Disconnected from the Principal and set the status "Disconnected" to each mirrored db's.
- **The Principal server is restarted after** a while (2-3 minutes an interval bigger than the mirroring timeout)

The questions is: After the restart of Principal - everything gets back to normal and the former Principal and Mirror will take their past places? The mirroring on Principal will be suspended and it must be resumed?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to manually fail it back over to the principal, you can do that by going right clicking on the database -> Task -> Mirror and click the Failover

Comment: thanks for answering but in safety = off manual failover is not supported. Actually I wanted to know if the mirrored databases will be online on Principal after this is back and either their mirroring status will be suspended.